# progressbar in asynctask not getting in onProgressUpdate

Tags: java, android

My asynctask not going in onProgressUpdate. why? I'm going to create progress bar in asynctask. Below is my code to show uploading image by using progress bar.

```
public static class RegisterDataEngineForPost extends AsyncTask<MultipartEntity, integer, String>{


    ProgressBar ProgressBarUpload;


    public void setmCurrentPhotoPath(ProgressBarUploadb) {

        ProgressBarUpload = ProgressBarUploadb;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(integer... values) {


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ProgressBarUpload.setProgress(0);
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(MultipartEntity... params) {


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you used `publishProgress()` method in `doInBackgroud()` ?

Comment: no i dont used. how to do that?

Comment: You have to define the limit of progress bar initially and in `doInBackGround()` you have to call the `publishProgress()` periodically. Simple example that you can refer http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...)

manually, Android will not know your progress out of nothing, you need to determine it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call publishProgress(progress_value) to update the progress like that

```
public static class RegisterDataEngineForPost extends AsyncTask<MultipartEntity, integer, String>{


ProgressBar ProgressBarUpload;


public void setmCurrentPhotoPath(ProgressBarUploadb) {

    ProgressBarUpload = ProgressBarUploadb;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(integer... values) {


}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    ProgressBarUpload.setProgress(0);
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(MultipartEntity... params) {
      //do some task and update the progress
   publishProgress(progress_value);

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }
}
}
```